# Substitution doesn't work if a string contains `\n` in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have text file which has some strings like `"string\n"` (including quotes). I need to put those strings into `<tags>` so there should be `<tag>"string\n"</tag>`. But substitution function doesn't work because of `\n`.

When print `$str` after `s///`, it still contains `some "string\n" + 25`.

```
 my $pattern = '"string\n"';

 my $str = 'some "string\n" + 25';

 $str =~ s/$pattern/25/;

 print "$str\n";
 print "$pattern\n";
```

Can you please help me to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution operator `s/pattern/substitution/` interprets its first argument as a pattern – characters like `(, ), [, ], +, *, .` etc. all have a special meaning here. Also, backslash sequences like `\A` or `\n` are interpreted. You are essentially doing `s/"string\n"/25/`, which obviously matches a newline.

To turn off the interpretation of special characters, use the`\Q…\E` command:  `s/\Q$string1[0]\E/25/`  will work. Always do this when substituting strings, not regex patterns.

Comment: You can also use `quotemeta` for an equivalent effect (see perlfunc).

Comment: this is exactly what I need. Works perfectly. Thanks to everyone for help

Answer (score 2):

The regex pattern `\n` matches a newline, but you don't have any newlines in the string against which you are trying to patch. If you want to match `\` followed by `n`, you need to use the pattern `\\n`.

To create the string containing `\\n`, you'll need to use

```
 '...\\\\n...'
```

or

```
 qr/...\\n.../
```

Comment: Thanks you. But I still don't know what I should do. I try =~ s/$match/<tag>$match</tag>/;. but if $match is "something\n" it just doesn't work...

Comment: In the code you do have, you'd use `my $pattern = qr/"string\\n"/;`. What you are now asking ("How do I generate a regex pattern that matches a string?") is a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11443547/589924).

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking at I thing

$str=~s/(.+?\\n").*/<tag>$1</tag>/;

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I have what you want correct:

You have a file that may have this line:

```
I would like to use "foo/n" as my tag.
```

And you want to be able to extract that `"foo/n" and put it like this:

```
<tag>"foo/n"</tag>
```

Let's try that example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $pattern = qr("\w+\\n");
my $string = q(I would like to be able to use "foo\n" as my tag);

say qq(Pattern = <$pattern>);
say qq(String = <$string>);
say "SUBSTITUTION";

$string =~ s/.*($pattern).*/<tag>$1<\/tag>/;

say qq(String = |$string|);
```

This prints out:

```
Pattern = <(?^:"\w+\\n")>
String = <I would like to be able to use "foo\n" as my tag>
SUBSTITUTION
String = |<tag>"foo\n"</tag>|
```

I used `<...>` and `|...|` as quotes in my output. They're not part of the actual results.

I used the `qr` to build my regular expression I can use later in my substitution command. I had to double up the `\` to quote the NL character, but otherwise, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

To include a literal string (one that doesn't contain special regular expression characters) you need to use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or `\Q` so that special characters are escaped.

```
 my $pattern = '"string\n"';
 my $str = 'some "string\n" + 25';

 $str =~ s/\Q$pattern\E/25/;

 print "$str\n";
 print "$pattern\n";
```

Outputs:

```
some 25 + 25
"string\n"
```

Note, `\E` indicates the end of the special escaping, but it would've been assumed in the above expression because it was at the end of the LHS.

Can always just include the pattern in the regex and escape it ourselves:

```
$str =~ s/"string\\n"/25/;
```